# Sort JSON data based on UTC timestamp in php from client side

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, usort

I have a JSON with some data. One of the fields is a timestamp. Is there any way to sort the data based on the timestamp? Please don't recommend me any jQuery plugins like DataTables. And I don't want to fetch the data from the database in sorted order either. I use the following SQL command.

```
select * from tablename;
```

I don't want to get the data in sorted form from database by using a command something like this.

```
select * from tablename ORDER BY.....
```

Is it possible to sort JSON data like what I've said using PHP??? I want the data to be sorted in the descending order based on the timestamp. Any suggestions???

Here is a sample data

http://codepad.viper-7.com/TyLOWV

I tried this...

```
function sortByYear($a, $b) {
    $dA = new DateTime($a['date']);
    $dB = new DateTime($b['date']);

    return $dA->format('y') - $dB->format('y');
}


$d = json_decode($sample_data, true);
$info = $d['date'];

usort($info, 'sortByYear');

print_r($info);
```

Comment: Why is this a MySQL question?

Comment: Look at the question once again?? @shmosel

Comment: I see that you want to sort a JSON dataset, and you *don't* want to do it in MySQL. So what makes this a MySQL question?

Comment: Who said this is a mysql question??? @shmosel

Comment: It had a "mysql" tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56315/discussion-between-the-joker-and-shmosel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [array_multisort](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) function in PHP

```
$date = array();
$d = json_decode($sample_data, true);
foreach ($d as $key => $row)
{
    $date[$key] = $row['date'];
}
array_multisort($date, SORT_DESC, $d);
```

Comment: So, the new sorted is stored in $date. Can I store in back to $d? @Sadikhasan

Comment: It will store in `$d` not in `$date`